# Script to send mail using function

Tags: bash, email, function, parameter

I am trying to write a bash script with a function which you use to send an email from the command line to an address and include a Cc address, a subject line, and an input file. For example, if the function is called "m," the typed command would look like:

```
m receiver@email.com receiver2@email.com SubjectLine TextFile.txt
```

Below is what I have done so far in vi. I am sure I am declaring the variables wrong, and much more, probably. I am very new to this.

```
m()
{
  mail -s="$1" -t="$2" -s="$3" #I am still unclear about positional parameters
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
m() {
    to_addr="$1"
    cc_addr="$2"
    subject="$3"
    body="$4"
    cat "$body" | mail -s "$subject" -c "$cc_addr" "$to_addr"
}

if [[ "$#" -eq 4 ]]; then
    m "$1" "$2" "$3" "$4"
else
    echo "Incorrect number of paramaters.  Aborting."
    echo "Example syntax:  $0 recipient@example.com ccrecipient@example.com "Message Subject" /path/to/messagebody.txt"
    exit 1
fi
```